# Use a reverse OneToOne relation in Django FileField upload_to

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to use the reverse relation of a `OneToOneField` to build the path in an `upload_to` method of a `FileField`, like this:

```
def get_upload_path(asset, filename):
    # Using the reverse relation `game` here
    return '/'.join([asset.game.slug, filename])


class Asset(models.Model)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path)


class Game(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    menu_image = models.OneToOneField(Asset, related_name='game', null=True, blank=True)
```

I can create a `Game` with an empty asset no problem. When I change the game in the admin, and I add a new `Asset` to the menu image via the green + button, I get a `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` error saying "Asset has no game" inside the popup. Is there a way to accomplish this? I've found some other answers saying it is, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962634/creating-a-dynamic-path-when-i-upload-images) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190697/django-filefield-with-upload-to-determined-at-runtime), but it's not working for me on Django 1.9.4.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your 'get_upload_path' function, cause you're calling to asset.game.slug... but you don't have defined any game yet...

Comment: I'm on the "Change game" page in the admin, after creating a game. I'm using the little green + button to add the asset. Does the popup not associate the game with the unsaved Asset instance?

Comment: you must especify what to do when you're saving a game... and then save a Asset... if you delete the upload_to function, i believe you dont have problems

Comment: Right, I know that's where the problem is coming from, I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to achieve what I'm trying to inside of the Django admin.